# Showing only two decimal numbers stored in array

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview, swift4

I have an array `var priceUSDcoin = [String]()` that contain many numbers comes from JSON data that have more than 2 decimal numbers like `2.073334` and i want all the numbers in the array have only 2 decimal numbers like `2.07`

I tried to use `String(format: "%.2f")` and failed

I called the `priceUSDcoin` here `cell.priceLable.text = "$" + priceUSDcoin[indexPath.row]` in my tableview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `NumberFormatter` to get the desired results. Using a single `flatMap` operation, you can convert all elements of your array to the desired format after converting the `String` prices to `Double`.

```
var priceUSDcoin = [String]()
priceUSDcoin = ["2.073334","1.245","0.1123"]

let priceFormatter = NumberFormatter()
priceFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
priceFormatter.minimumIntegerDigits = 1

let priceUSD = priceUSDcoin.flatMap{ priceString->String? in
    guard let price = Double(priceString) else {return nil}
    return priceFormatter.string(for: price)
}
print(priceUSD)
```

Output:

> ["2.07", "1.24", "0.11"]

If you want to display the prices to the user, you can even set `priceFormatter.numberStyle = .currency`, in which case the results will be formatted as currency using the user's Locale settings. Since your prices are all in USD, you can hardcode the `Locale` using `priceFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")`.

Output:

> ["$2.07", "$1.24", "$0.11"]

Comment: Note that the prices are in US$. You should use a fixed locale `"en_US_POSIX"` or at least set the number formatter currency symbol to dollar `"$"`.

Answer (score 1):

> I have an array `var priceUSDcoin = [String]()` that contain many numbers comes from JSON

You shouldn't convert `numbers` from JSON to `String` type. Try to save them to `Double` type. In this case your code (with little update) works fine:

```
let priceUSDcoin = [2.073334] // Array of `Double`
print(String(format: "%.2f", priceUSDcoin[0])) // prints 2.07
```